# Replace lines in a multi-line string

Tags: regex, perl, weblogic

I have an Oracle WebLogic `config.xml` file read into a string. I'm looking to update a series of lines in it. I've verified that I'm reading the file, getting the lines set, and able to update the correct line with the parameters I'm looking for, but I can't seem to update the original string.

Here's the main loop:

```perl
while ( $lines =~ m{(<arguments>.*?</arguments>)}mgs ) {

    my $nchunk = my $ochunk = $1;

    print "#" . '=' x 70 . "\n";

    my ($ms)  = $ochunk =~ m{.*/(.*?)\.out.*};
    my $nname = $monster->{$domain}->{$ms}->{nodeName};
    my $tname = $monster->{$domain}->{$ms}->{tierName};

    my $newentry = sprintf(" %s %s.nodeName=-Dappdynamics.agent.nodeName=%s",
            $appdjar, $ms, $nname);
    $newentry .= " $ms.appdynamics.tierName=-Dappdynamics.tierName=$tname";

    $nchunk =~ s/(<\/arguments>)/$newentry\1/g;

    print "$ochunk\n";
    print "#" . '-' x 70 . "\n";
    print "$nchunk\n";

    # $lines =~ s!$ochunk!!msg;
    # $lines =~ s!$ochunk!$nchunk!msg;
}
```

As written, that results in:

```
#======================================================================
<arguments>-Xms512m -Xmx512m -Dweblogic.system.BootIdentityFile=/opt/app/oracle/user_projects/domains/AccountingServices_Domain/boot.properties -Dweblogic.Stdout=/opt/app/oracle/user_projects/logs/AccountingServices_Domain/AccountingCommon_MS1.out -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError  -XX:HeapDumpPath=/opt/app/oracle/user_projects/logs/AccountingServices_Domain/dumps  -XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures  -XX:+FlightRecorder  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=40124  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false  -XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+FlightRecorder  -XX:FlightRecorderOptions=defaultrecording=true,disk=true,repository=/opt/app/oracle/user_projects/logs/AccountingServices_Domain,maxage=10m,dumponexit=true,dumponexitpath=/opt/app/oracle/user_projects/logs/AccountingServices_Domain  -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+DebugNonSafepoints -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/opt/app/oracle/user_projects/applications/AccountingServices_Domain/log4j.xml</arguments>
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
<arguments>-Xms512m -Xmx512m -Dweblogic.system.BootIdentityFile=/opt/app/oracle/user_projects/domains/AccountingServices_Domain/boot.properties -Dweblogic.Stdout=/opt/app/oracle/user_projects/logs/AccountingServices_Domain/AccountingCommon_MS1.out -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError  -XX:HeapDumpPath=/opt/app/oracle/user_projects/logs/AccountingServices_Domain/dumps  -XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures  -XX:+FlightRecorder  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=40124  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false  -XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+FlightRecorder  -XX:FlightRecorderOptions=defaultrecording=true,disk=true,repository=/opt/app/oracle/user_projects/logs/AccountingServices_Domain,maxage=10m,dumponexit=true,dumponexitpath=/opt/app/oracle/user_projects/logs/AccountingServices_Domain  -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+DebugNonSafepoints -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/opt/app/oracle/user_projects/applications/AccountingServices_Domain/log4j.xml -javaagent:/opt/app/appdynamics/universal-agent/monitor/java/javaagent.jar AccountingCommon_MS1.nodeName=-Dappdynamics.agent.nodeName=AccountingCommon_2123 AccountingCommon_MS1.appdynamics.tierName=-Dappdynamics.tierName=AccountingCommon</arguments>
[[snip]]
```

I can't seem to 're-find' the source chunk as indicated by one of those commented $lines trying to replace `$ochunk` with nothing.

Comment: What are `$monster`, `$domain`, and `$appdjar`? See [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: $monster is the monster hash It's the graveyard bash!  :)  Showing my age, I guess.  It's a hash containing the parameters that need to be updated.  We can see those are set correctly by scrolling the output to the far right.  The second line shows how the first line should be updated.    Thanks.

Comment: *"I can't seem to 're-find' the source chunk as indicated by one of those commented $lines trying to replace $ochunk with nothing"* I can't guess what this might mean, and since it appears to be a statement if the problem, I think it's quite important.

Comment: Don't add the `/m` modifier when it's unnecessary. Don't use `\1` etc. in strings: they should be `$1` etc.

Comment: "# $lines =~ s!$ochunk!!ms;"  attempts to find $ochunk in $lines and replace it with nothing.  That's what i meant.  The /m is needed as $lines is a multi-line string.  /g, on the other hand, from what I'm reading, is an issue.    Thanks.

Comment: Yes, but I don't see why you're troubled about a statement that has been commented out. In fact I really don't see what your problem is at all. Writing `/m` shouldn't be a knee-jerk reaction to a multi-line string: it affects only the metacharacters `^` and `$` which you don't use, so it's unnecessary. On the other hand, `/g` is essential if you want the `while` to make any sense.

Comment: That line was only commented out for the purposes of proving the variables are set correctly.  The shortest possible problem statement is that I need to replace $ochunk with $nchunk in $lines.  Right now, those lines look like:

  $lines =~ s!$ochunk!!ee;
# $lines =~ s!$ochunk!$nchunk!ee;

and still not working.    Thanks again.

Comment: FWIW, I've also tried no modifiers "$lines =~ s!$ochunk!!;" w/no success.

Comment: Your `/ee` won't work unless `$nchunk` contains Perl code.

Comment: yea, didn't figure it would.  pretty much grasping at straws at this point... thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going about this in a very round-about way, which is why I couldn't fathom what you were trying to do for the longest time. What you're *actually* trying to do is

> Insert an additional string after the existing text in an `arguments` element

And you need just a substitution. I've left it global in case there really are multiple such elements in the XML. I've not been able to test it, but I do know that it compiles

```
$lines =~ s{ (<arguments>) (.*?) (</arguments>) }{

    my ($otag, $text, $ctag)  = ($1, $2, $3);
    my ($ms)   = $text =~ m{.*/(.*?)\.out};

    my $msdata = $monster->{$domain}{$ms};
    my $node   = $msdata->{nodeName};
    my $tier   = $msdata->{tierName};

    my $newentry = " $appdjar $ms.nodeName=-Dappdynamics.agent.nodeName=$node";
    $newentry   .= " $ms.appdynamics.tierName=-Dappdynamics.tierName=$tier";

    $otag . $text . $newentry . $ctag;
}segx
```

Comment: That is sweet!  I always think 'loop' when I go through these exercises.  Wouldn't have thought of handling the work in the replacement section in a million years.  Excellent, sir!  Thank you very much.  In case you're interested, there's 8 <arg></arg> sections in the test file.  Other files will probably have even more.  Thanks again.  Excellent!